# How to provide data for sendTransaction using web3.js 1.0

Tags: web3js-v1.x, sendtransaction

I'm using web3.js 1.0. I want to use `sendTransaction` method to call a contract method, but I don't know how to provide `data` parameter for it.
For example suppose we have a contract named `myContract` and the method `setValue` in it, then we want to call the method with two parameters: 123 as `uint` and 'ABC' as `string`. so we have:

```
nodeUrl='...';
abi=...;
contractAddress='0x...';
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(nodeUrl));
myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,contractAddress);
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: '0x...',
    data: data
}, function(error, hash){
    ...
});
```

And we want to use the method as follows:

```
setValue(123,'ABC');
```

How can we set the `data` value for `sendTransaction` method?

P.S: I don't want to use Metamask. I am using my account directly in my javascript code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
data: myContract.methods.setValue(123,'ABC').encodeABI()
```

BTW, you'll first need to unlock on your node the account that you specify in the `from` field (otherwise, you'll need to use `web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction` instead).

Answer (score 0):

No need to set the data manually. You can use the web3 contract methods function. In your case, you can call the `setValue(123,'ABC')` like this:

```
myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,contractAddress);
myContract.methods.setValue(123,'ABC')
.send({
     from: youraccount.address,
     to: myContract.options.address,
     value: 0, // Don't send ETH, this is a contract transaction
})
```

See the [web3 docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send) for more information.

Keep in mind that this is not a "call". Your function changes the state of the smart contract. You can use [methods.myMethod.call](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call) for executing EVM functions that do not create a transaction.

P.S: I don't want to use Metamask. I am using my account directly in my javascript code.

Comment: I don't want to use Metamask. I am using my account directly in my javascript code.